# Elements relative to screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out how to render different elements in my web page such that they all appear the same relative size regardless of screen size. However, when I review my webpage and change the height of my browser, the elements do not change in size as well. How do I achieve this affect? Please see [this url](https://young-beach-18801.herokuapp.com/) and the dropdown menu, specifically the "cv" element. Thanks!

Comment: the cv element drives you to localhost

Comment: Please post some code so we can understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried vh instead of px?